# Is WebLogic 12c cerified to work with IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, weblogic

Our web app works fine if it resides on `WebLogic 12c` server and the client is `IE11`. It doesn't work if client is `IE9` or `IE10`. Is `WebLogic 12c` cerified to work with IE9?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works with IE 9. You can download the certification matrix from the Oracle site [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-1211x-certmatrix-1395408.xls)

If you have a specific error in your server logs, please add that to your question.